# a function to get value and id of an input form based on user input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, input

I have several inputs. When a user enters something in an input I want to get its value and id using a function. What's the best way to do it?

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="id1">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="id2">
.
.
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="id9">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="id10">



<script>
function getIdVal(){
// how to get those values and ids from this function?
}
</script>
```

Comment: "When a user enters something...." Can you clarfiy this?  Do you mean on every key stroke, or what?

Comment: so add an event listener and read the value. Basic JavaScript concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `change/keyup/keydown` event (which can be replaced to another event if needed) you can do something like this:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" onchange="run(this)" id="id1">
<input type="number" class="form-control" onchange="run(this)" id="id2">

<input type="number" class="form-control" onchange="run(this)" id="id9">
<input type="number" class="form-control" onchange="run(this)" id="id10">
```

And for your JS

```
function run(ele){
  var id = ele.id;
  var value = ele.value;
  console.log(id, value);
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp7bx0wo/).

Answer (score 0):

try this. whenever you type something(include backspace), the key event onkeyup is fired and `getIdVal` function will be called.

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" onkeyup="getIdVal(this)" id="id1">
<input type="number" class="form-control" onkeyup="getIdVal(this)" id="id2">
.
.
<input type="number" class="form-control" onkeyup="getIdVal(this)" id="id9">
<input type="number" class="form-control" onkeyup="getIdVal(this)" id="id10">



<script>
function getIdVal(obj) {
    // how to get those values and ids from this function?
    console.log(obj.id)
    console.log(obj.value)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="fname1" onkeyup="myFunction('fname1');">
<input type="text" id="fname2" onkeyup="myFunction('fname2');">

 function myFunction(ids) {
    var x = document.getElementById(ids);
   alert("Value: "+x.value  + "  ID: "+x.id);
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.